# VS 2010 professional edition keeps showing running at the top

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-chrome

I mostly debug my aspx pages in chrome. It works fine and my breakpoint does get hit. However, I have a problem. Even though I close the browser the VS 2010 professional edition keeps showing running at the top of the taskbar. How can I get rid of this bug? It really annoys me. Everytime I have to manually click the menu item of "Stop debugging". I've noticed that this doesn't happen when I debug in IE9. But I want to debug in Chrome only.

Comment: Its not a bug, its perfectly normal behavior, VS 2010 has no idea you have closed chrome.

Comment: @Downvoter: no need for a -1 though. he wants a solution and i guess thats alright

Comment: @Ben: So how does he know that IE9 is closed? Because it is Microsoft product?

Comment: @Anthony: dont you have a "Restart Debugging" button? It works the same as stop and start.

Comment: @Ben: If VS knows how Chrome started and it can normally hit the breakpoints why can't it know that Chrome stopped working so VS should stop debugging...

Comment: He wants a solution for having to click "stop debugging" to get the debugger to stop debugging.  Not sure i would classify that as a problem, it's a bit like wanting a solution to having to use a doorknob for opening doors, because some other doors open automatically when you approach them.

Comment: @naveen: No, no restart debugging option is available that I can see. I have attach to process option and I can attach to chrome but can't find any restart debugging option.

Comment: VS is not debugging chrome, it is debugging the web server, it is just firing off a process to start chrome as a convenience, chrome would have to send it an "i have closed" message.

Comment: @Ben: So any plugin is available for Chrome that I can install that sends this "I have closed" message?

Comment: @Anthony not that I am aware of, as Mrchief says in his answer if it spawned chrome as a child process or if it used some form of poling then it could do what you want.  I guess MS thought that having to click "stop debugging" to get VS to stop debugging was not that big a deal.

Comment: @Ben: "MS thought"! Atleast it is a big deal for me where I spend most of day in VS and keep debugging. Everytime I try to write some code in code behind I am unable to write and then I get reminded that it is because I did not stop debugging. Then I have to click on stop debugging and then start writing code. It is alright but it distracts and is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely IE is your default browser. So when you launch debugging from VS (via F5), VS spwans it as its child process. In that case, when the child quites, it knows the child has terminated and stops debugging.

If you open Chrome yourself and browser to your site, the breakpoing is hit becuase VS is attached the worker process, not the browser. It has no idea when you close the browser as it is no t its child process.

If this is your case, then there is no bug. To stop debugging, you have to stop it via VS in that case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your explanation is all right but IE is not my default browser. I have installed http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921 and set Chrome as my default browser.

Comment: I checked this out. So it does seem that VS knows about IE (most likely it relies on some return value/event that IE only sends or maybe both being MS products, there is some harmony). It doesn't close FF/Chrome even if they spawn as child processes. There are other similar SO questions that are unanswered. Hate to suggest this, but I guess you need report this on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: I have checked because there is no answer to this question but you pointed me in right direction. Thanks!